# having trouble with dnf-automatic notification

Tags: python, linux, fedora, centos8, dnf

My machine is running Rockylinux 8. I would like to receive the notifications by email, but I believe that I have to self-host a SMTP server if that's correct.

So I find out [Gotify](https://gotify.net/) as a notification tool for my phone. I want dnf-automatic to execute a gotify-cli command, which kind of looks like this, as "body" is the body of the message:

```
gotify push "body"
```

Here's part of the config file for dnf-automatic:

```
[emitters]
emit_via = command

[command]
# The shell command to execute. This is a Python format string, as used in
# str.format(). The format function will pass a shell-quoted argument called
# `body`.
command_format = "gotify push"

# The contents of stdin to pass to the command. It is a format string with the
# same arguments as `command_format`.
stdin_format = "{body}"
```

Am I setting this up correctly? I have no experience in Python. And does anyone knows how to change how often the machine runs dnf-automatic.timer, so I can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
[emitters]
emit_via = command

[command]
command_format = gotify push "{body}"
```

For reference, [this](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/blob/ef3b6c9c4f88164cb986c93ce3870b634881a3d3/dnf/automatic/emitter.py#L124-L151) is the code that interpolates the `body` variable into your command.

Unless your command reads the standard input you can ignore the `stdin_format`, which gets defaulted to `{body}` anyway ([source](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/blob/395541fbf8f87f81cdca7567f22be1182e55bea7/dnf/automatic/main.py#L198-L207)).